# ¿Cómo unir dos registros referidos a distintas tablas?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentado hacer dos registros distintos en dos tablas distintas en `phpMyAdmin`. No sé como hacer para combinarlas de forma que me haga las inserciones correctamente en cada una de las tablas, ya que hasta ahora solo me hace en una.

Este es el fragmento de la consulta

```
$query = "INSERT INTO personas (nombre, apellido1, Direccion) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido1','$Direccion')";

$query = "INSERT INTO vehiculos (Marca, Modelo, Color) VALUES ('$Marca','$Modelo','$Color')";    

if (mysqli_query($enlaceBD,$query)) {
    echo "<p>Registro agregado.</p>"; 
} else {
    echo "<p>No se agregó. Error: ".mysqli_error($enlaceBD)."</p>";
}
```

Comment: Probaste uniendo ambas sentencias en una misma variable? $query = "INSERT INTO personas (nombre, apellido1, Direccion) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido1','$Direccion'); INSERT INTO vehiculos (Marca, Modelo, Color) VALUES ('$Marca','$Modelo','$Color')";

Comment: Sí, pero da error

Comment: Realmente lo que estas ejecutando unicamente es la segunda query ya que sobreescribes la primera al asignar esta segunda. Lo que necesitas es ejecutar 2 querys y ademas hacerlas dentro de una transsaccion. Aparte y creo que deberías revisar como hacer consultas preparadas pues tal como lo tienes tu codigo es muy vulnerable a ataques.

Comment: Algún ejemplo de como ejecutar 2 querys dentro de una transaccion?

Comment: no sera por que la tienes la variable query 2 veces , cambia una variable a query2 e intenta denuevo

Answer (score 1):

Para enviar varias consultas al mismo tiempo `mysqli` cuenta con una función llamada [**`multi_query`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php) la cual:

> Ejecuta una o múltiples consultas concatenadas por puntos y comas.

El uso es muy simple. Sólo hay que cuidar que las consultas estén separadas por punto y coma dentro de la cadena, quedando algo como:  `INSERT INTO tabla1 (col1) VALUES ('val1'); INSERT INTO tabla2 (col2) VALUES (val2); INSERT INTO tablaN (colN) VALUES ('valN');`

Pero, conviene controlar los posibles errores de inserción. Eso no es tratado en el Manual de PHP, pero podemos hacerlo con [un código propuesto en las notas de contribución](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php#106126).

Consiste en:

- Poner las consultas en un array
- Dividirlas con `implode` agregando el `;` ente cada una
- recurrir a `next_result()` para controlar las consultas fallidas. Este método devuelve `false` si se queda sin declaraciones o si la siguiente instrucción tiene un error. Por lo tanto, es importante verificar si hay errores cuando finaliza el ciclo. El código permite además saber cuándo y dónde se rompió el bucle. Y el motivo, capturando el error.

Tendríamos entonces:

```
/*
  *Ponemos las consultas en un array. 
  *Nótese que aquí no ponemos ;
  *ya que lo haremos en el implode*/ 

$querys = array(
                 "INSERT INTO personas (nombre, apellido1, Direccion) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido1','$Direccion')", 
                 "INSERT INTO vehiculos (Marca, Modelo, Color) VALUES ('$Marca','$Modelo','$Color')"
                ); 
/*Aquí ponemos el ; requerido como separador de cada consulta*/
if ($enlaceBD->multi_query(implode(';', $querys))) { 
    $i = 0; 
    do { 
        $i++; 
    } while ($mysqli->next_result()); 
    } 
if ($mysqli->errno) { 
    echo "Ejecución terminada prematuramente en la consulta $i".PHP_EOL; 
    var_dump($querys[$i], $enlaceBD->error); 
}
```

Si quieres evitar el control de errores, puedes hacer simplemente esto, aunque no es recomendable:

```
$querys = array(
                 "INSERT INTO personas (nombre, apellido1, Direccion) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido1','$Direccion')", 
                 "INSERT INTO vehiculos (Marca, Modelo, Color) VALUES ('$Marca','$Modelo','$Color')"
                ); 
$enlaceBD->multi_query(implode(';', $querys));
```

---

> **NOTA SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD:**
>
> Este código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Debes
>   considerar sin demora la posibilidad de usar consultas preparadas.

---

> **NOTA SOBRE LA OPTIMIZACIÓN:**
>
> No uses `multi_query` si su uso no es justificado. A veces puede
>   revelar un mal diseño del modelo de datos o de la lógica que estás
>   implementando. No he verificado si es posible usar `multi_query` con
>   consultas preparadas. Si no es posible, no sacrifiques tu programa
>   usando esa funcionalidad pasando por encima de la seguridad.

Answer (score 0):

En tu código, lo que estás haciendo es sobreescribir el primer valor de la variable con el segundo.

```
// Asignás el valor a la variable $query
$query = "INSERT INTO personas (nombre, apellido1, Direccion) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido1','$Direccion')";

// Reemplazás el valor de la variable $query    
$query = "INSERT INTO vehiculos (Marca, Modelo, Color) VALUES ('$Marca','$Modelo','$Color')";
```

Si hay una precedencia en tus queries, podés insertar uno y si se insertó correctamente, insertás el segundo.

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO personas (nombre, apellido1, Direccion) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido1','$Direccion')";

$query2 = "INSERT INTO vehiculos (Marca, Modelo, Color) VALUES ('$Marca','$Modelo','$Color')";    

if (mysqli_query($enlaceBD,$query1)) {
    if (mysqli_query($enlaceBD,$query2)) {
        echo "<p>Registros agregado.</p>"; 
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>No se agregó. Error: ".mysqli_error($enlaceBD)."</p>";
}
```